# Bottom aligned container using flexbox causing problem with media screen

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

I have the following...
[image: ImageBEFORE]
...and I want to stack the blue container (with box 10 and 20) when outer green container width falls below 500px, like this:
[image: ImageAFTER]
I'm using media screen to do this but the fiddle shows how the stacking doesn't work properly and enters the brown container. The stacking works fine when the blue container is allowed to locate at the top of the green container using a relative position, but it fails when I locate it at the bottom using absolute. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```css
#TOTALcontainer {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px;
}

#outerLHcontainer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  margin: 5px;
}

#LHcontainer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 10px;
  margin-right: 12vw;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

#RHcontainer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}

#div10,
#div20 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  #outerLHcontainer {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="TOTALcontainer">
      <div id="outerLHcontainer">
        <div id="LHcontainer">
          <div id="div1">1</div>
          <div id="div2">2</div>
          <div id="div3">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="RHcontainer">
        <div id="div10">10</div>
        <div id="div20">20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pb2gckL5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go probaly another way to do it. Simply with flexbox:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    the item of the left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br> 
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-block">
      blue block
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.left, .right {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: 5px;
}
.left {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left, .right {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/priatelko/pen/oNYoKga

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it doesn't seem to get result I'm after.

Comment: Maybe I miss understood. So you want to hold the blue container in top? Like the first image? And below 500px stuck it down, like in your image2?

Comment: Exactly.  The images are a 'before' and a desired 'after', respectively.  To replicate the 'before' issue in the fiddle just edit the CSS position from 'relative' to 'absolute' in the jsfiddle in #RHcontainer.  You can then see how flexing the window width produces the wrong kind of stacking.

Comment: I just edited my answer. I guess that is what you looking for.

Comment: Much appreciate your efforts @Maxo but it's not quite there. When I collapse the window width, your example doesn't show the RH container collapsing to stack underneath the LH container, as it shows in my 2nd image.

Comment: I am sorry dude, maybe my english is wrong, but when I can see my codepen in window port width about 500px, the blue block is bellow the green one (stacked undermeath). Screenshot as you can see: [link](https://postimg.cc/Z0dxGVgz)

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it's weird!  I had to increase the max width from 499 to 599 for it to work on my browser (Chrome).  Many thanks for your help on this @Maxo, much appreciated.